# a Form on a slider (HTML & CSS)

Tags: html, css

So i have a form, but i want it on my slider. The form is in a div and the slider is aswell. 
This is the HTML

```
  <div id="slider" >
     <figure>
   <img src="slider1.png" >
    <img src="allevoertuigen.png">
    <img src="THEORIECURSUS.png">
   <img src="PAKKETTEN.png">
   <img src="CONTACT.PNG">
    </figure>
    </div>
```

This is the CSS

```
 @keyframes slider {

     0% {
left: 0;
    }

20% {
left: 0;
  } 

25% {
left: -100
   }

45% {
left: -100%
  }

   50% {
left: -200%;
   }

   70% {
left: -200%;
  }

  75% {
left: -300%
  }

  95% {
left: -300%;
}

 100% {
left: -400%;
 }

 }

  #slider {
overflow: hidden;
 }

 #slider figure img {
width: 20%;
float: left;
 }

 #slider figure {
position: relative;
width: 500%;
margin: 0;
left: 0;
text-align: left;
font-size: 0;
animation: 20s slider infinite;
 }
```

Form is a div with a form tag with labels and submit buttons in it. IF you guys still need the Form code too, here is the gyazo of it. :

https://gyazo.com/1280234e8f37ae6bd8d01bb265ad61d4

Answer (score 0):

I`ve found some things missing in the beginning of the css

```
0% {left: 0;}
20% {left: 0;}
25% {left: -100;}
45% {left: -100%;}
50% {left: -200%;}
70% {left: -200%;}
75% {left: -300%;}
95% {left: -300%;}
100% {left: -400%;}
```

Maybe is just that.